# Nao consigo passar Metodos como Parametro em PHP

Tags: php, laravel, funções

Tenho o seguinte codigo

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DatesController extends Controller
{
    //Função que calcula o inicio e o fim da semana a partir do dia 
    public static function getWeekBeginEnd($day)
    {
        $day = strtotime($day);
        //Pega o dia da semana
        $number_of_day = date('w', $day);
        intval($number_of_day);
        //Começa a contar a semana na segunda
        $number_of_day--;
        //Clcula o primeiro dia da Semana
        if ($number_of_day < 0) {
            $begin_week = strtotime('-7 days', $day);
        }
        else
            $begin_week = strtotime('-'.$number_of_day.' days', $day);
        // Calcula o ultimo da semana
        $end_week = strtotime('+7 days', $begin_week);
        //Coloca os dados numa array
        $week['begin'] = date('Y-m-d', $begin_week);
        $week['end'] = date('Y-m-d', $end_week);
        //retorna a array
        return $week;
    }

    public function currentYear()
    {
        $current_year = date("Y");
        return $current_year;
    }

    public function currentMonth()
    {
        $current_month = date("m");
        return $current_month;
    }

    public function yearBegin($current_year = currentYear())
    {
        $year_begin = $current_year."-01-01";
        return $year_begin;
    }

    public function yearEnd($current_year = currentYear())
    {
        $year_end = $current_year."-12-31";
        return $year_end;
    }

    public function thisMonthBegin($current_year = currentYear(), $current_month = currentMonth())
    {
        $this_month_begin = $current_year."-".$current_month."-01";
    }

    public function nextMonth($current_month = currentMonth())
    {
        $next_month = $current_month + 1;
        if (strlen($next_month) == 1) {
            $next_month = "0".$next_month;
        }
        return $next_month;
    }

    public function nextMonthBegin($current_year = currentYear(), $next_month = nextMonth())
    {
        $next_month_begin = $current_year."-".$next_month."-01";
        return $next_month_begin;
    }

    public function now()
    {
        $now = date("Y-m-d H:i");
        return $now;
    }

    public function today()
    {
        $today = date("Y-m-d");
        return $today;
    }

    public function todayWithoutSeparators()
    {
        $todaywithoutseparators = date("Ymd");
        return $todaywithoutseparators;
    }

    public function todayTimeStamp($today = today())
    {
        $today_timestamp = strtotime($today);
        return $today_timestamp;
    }

    public function yesterdayTimeStamp($today_timestamp = todayTimeStamp())
    {
        $yesterday_timestamp = strtotime("-1 day", $today_timestamp);
        return $yesterday_timestamp;
    }

    public function yesterday($yesterday_timestamp = yesterdayTimeStamp())
    {
        $yesterday = date("Y-m-d", $yesterday_timestamp);
        return $yesterday;
    }

    public function tomorrowTimestamp($today_timestamp = todayTimeStamp())
    {
        $tomorrow_timestamp = strtotime("+1 day", $today_timestamp);
        return $tomorrow_timestamp;
    }

    public function tomorrow($tomorrow_timestamp = tomorrowTimestamp())
    {
        $tomorrow = date("Y-m-d", $tomorrow_timestamp);
        return $tomorrow;
    }

    public function aftomorrowTimestamp($today_timestamp = todayTimeStamp())
    {
        $aftomorrow_timestamp = strtotime("+2 day", $today_timestamp);
        return $aftomorrow_timestamp;
    }

    public function aftomorrow($aftomorrow_timestamp = aftomorrowTimestamp())
    {
        $aftomorrow = date("Y-m-d", $aftomorrow_timestamp);
        return $aftomorrow;
    }

    public function twoDaysAgoTimestamp($today_timestamp = todayTimeStamp())
    {
        $two_days_ago_timestamp = strtotime("+3 day", $today_timestamp);
        return $two_days_ago_timestamp;
    }

    public function twoDaysAgo($two_days_ago_timestamp = twoDaysAgoTimestamp())
    {
        $two_days_ago = date("Y-m-d", $two_days_ago_timestamp);
        return $two_days_ago;
    }

}
```

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro no ultimo metodo:

Constant expression contains invalid operations

Como corrigir ?

Att:

Com base na resposta do colega abaixo resolvi desta forma :

```
public static function currentYear()
{
    $current_year = date("Y");
    return $current_year;
}

public static function currentMonth()
{
    $current_month = date("m");
    return $current_month;
}

public static function yearBegin()
{
    $current_year = $this->currentYear();
    $year_begin = $current_year."-01-01";
    return $year_begin;
}
```

Comment: Não pode definir uma função como valor padrão de um parametro.

Comment: @rray e o que devo fazer para passar o resultado para o metodo seguinte ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que tenha dois erros, primeiro `currentYear()` irá procurar uma função e não um método dentro da classe:

```
$current_year = currentYear()
```

Para acessar o método é necessário `$this`

Segundo, mesmo que faça isto:

```
... yearBegin($current_year = $this->currentYear()) {
```

Não iria funcionar, pois o `$this` não seria acessivel, o que recomendo é usar `null` como parametro padrão e fazer uma `if` para checar, assim:

```
public function yearBegin($current_year = null)
{
    $current_year = $current_year ? $current_year : $this->currentYear();

    $year_begin = $current_year."-01-01";
    return $year_begin;
}
```

Comment: Também é um opção.

Comment: Foi a melhor ! show Guilherme.

Answer (score 0):

O correto é usar a "`variável`" na classe e não somente nos métodos.
Exemplo:

```
<?php

class DatesController 
{

    private $year;

    //Função que calcula o inicio e o fim da semana a partir do dia 

    //... restante da classe

    public function setCurrentYear()
    {
        //return $this -> year = date('Y');
       return $this -> year = date('Y');
    }

    public function yearBegin()
    {
        $year_begin = $this->setCurrentYear()."-01-01";
        return $year_begin;
    }

}

$obj = new DatesController();
echo $obj -> yearBegin();
```

Na verdade não teria porque ter um setter "automático", lembre-se disso !

Toda essa classe não entendi o motivo dela, mas fazendo o que você quer, está aí !

Comment: Deu erro: Using $this when not in object context

Comment: Posta sua classe toda para vermos.

Comment: Postei a classe toda @Raoni BZ

Comment: Yuri, refiz e testei o código sem a extensão da classe, e o resto dos código só para ver e entender como seria, pois não entendi a necessidade de alguns métodos.

Answer (score -1):

o PHP não é uma linguagem funcional, neste caso, vc não vai conseguir passar um método como parâmetro, vc pode fazer assim.

```
$current_year = currentYear();//atribui o retorno do método a variável $current_year
```

`yearBegin($current_year);// passa como parametro a variavel $current_year`

Comment: A variável `$current_year` está definida somente para o método `currentYear()`, dessa forma a mesma não tem valor fora do método.